# What cellphone is the best for photographs?

Tags: camera-recommendation

What cellphone is the best for photographs? With a very good camera, a very high definition and that can zoom in very good and far while keeping it's high definition. I know about the Nokia Lumia with a 41 megapixel camera, but is there anything better?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE. Please take a moment to read the help section on which questions you [should](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ask here and which questions are [off-topic](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Your question is not a good fit for the SE format. Firstly you ask what the "best" is. Although you state some criteria it's still vague (what do you consider high-def?). Secondly, the answer to this question will only be valid for a short time. When a new phone comes out it's not useful anymore. Hence, shopping questions are generally off-topic here.

Comment: A better approach for your problem is to look at review sites and decide for yourself. Here's a good one to start with: http://connect.dpreview.com/phone-reviews?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=mainmenu&utm_medium=text&ref=mainmenu

Comment: I don't think anything will top the lumia 1020 and 1520 at the moment..

Comment: The Nokia 1020 is the best that there is for now. See [Smartphones vs DSLRs vs film](http://connect.dpreview.com/post/5533410947/smartphones-versus-dslr-versus-film). But for "zoom in very far while keeping the high definiton" - sorry, then you'll need something more than a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of what you mean by "very high definition". The big problem with digital cameras in cellphones is their small sensors and absence of quality glass to complement it. The cameras might very well have incredible megapixel count, but that doesn't help much when the pixel density is so high that they signal to noice ratio is really bad.

The Nokia you're referring to might be a good camera compared to much of the competition, but with my point of reference it and the other top camera phones simply does not deliver anything that remotely resembles your prerequisites "a very good camera, a very high definition and that can zoom in very good and far while keeping it's high definition".

As stated in the comments you should head to [http://connect.dpreview.com/](http://connect.dpreview.com/phone-reviews?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=mainmenu&utm_medium=text&ref=mainmenu) and compare the phones yourself.

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer)
IMO, all recent phones will do a good job in good lighting conditions for static scenes (landscape, architectural, portrait ....)

As soon as you want to take pictures of dynamic scenes (moving objects) or in less than idea lighting conditions, you will see a fast degradation of quality (blurred images, overly noisy images, weird color rendering...) (even with the flash)

Also have a look at the different photography oriented "app" available on the different platforms (iOS, Android, ... ), some are better than others

Look for comparative reviews (dpreview, ...) for both the phone and the different photography applications.